# How to get the value from table B whose max date is less than the date in table A

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables; table A and table B. Table A has StoreNumber, MatNumber and Date. Table B has StoreNumber, MatNumber, Date and ShipmentValue. I have to get the Shipment value from table B  for StoreNumber and MatNumber given that the Maximum Date in Table B for the StoreNumber and MatNumber should be less than the Date for the same StoreNumber and MatNumber in Table A (each row in Table A) . Please see the output table.

Table A:

```
StoreNumber MatNumber   Date
  A            9    3/30/2020
  A            9    3/30/2020
  B           10    3/18/2020
  B           10    3/18/2020
  A            9    3/13/2020
```

Table B:

```
StoreNumber MatNumber   Date    ShipmentValue
       A           9    3/10/2020   2
       A           9    3/12/2020   3
       A           9    3/18/2020   4
       B          10    3/4/2020    7
       B          10    3/7/2020    9
       B          10    3/16/2020   10
```

Output:

```
StoreNumber MatNumber   A.Date  B.Date  ShipmentValue
       A           9    3/30/2020   3/18/2020   4
       A           9    3/30/2020   3/18/2020   4
       B          10    3/18/2020   3/16/2020   10
       B          10    3/18/2020   3/16/2020   10
       A           9    3/13/2020   3/12/2020   3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a place where a [lateral join](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html) is handy:

```
select a.*, b.date, b.shipmentvalue
from a left join lateral
     (select b.*
      from b
      where b.storenumber = a.storenumber and
            b.matnumber = a.matnumber and
            b.date <= a.date
      order by b.date desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) b
     on 1=1;  -- returns rows in a even when there are no matches
```

EDIT:

Wow.  Snowflake implements lateral joins and then limits them in a fundamental way.  Another method is more expensive but should work:

```
select ab.*, b.shipmentValue
from (select a.StoreNumber, a.MatNumber, a.Date, max(b.date) as b_date, b.shipmentvalue
      from a left join
           b 
           on b.storenumber = a.storenumber and
              b.matnumber = a.matnumber and
              b.date <= a.date
      group by a.StoreNumber, a.MatNumber, a.Date
     ) ab join
     b
     on b.storenumber = ab.storenumber and
        b.matnumber = ab.matnumber and
        b.date <= ab.b_date
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am receiving the following error: SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated. Does this query supported by Snowflake?

Comment: Looks like Snowflake doesn't support `from a left join lateral`.  Try changing to `from a, lateral (`

Comment: Problem is arising because of fetch first 1 row only. When I commented it, the query is running. I even tried limit 1 but it throws the same error.

Comment: @Ashish . . . That is really disconcerting.  They support lateral joins, but not completely -- and it is not documented.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with ROW_NUMBER and selecting 1st row after ordering date by desc.

```
SELECT  A.StoreNumber 
        ,A.MatNumber  
        ,A.Date 
        ,B.Date AS B_Date   
        ,B.ShipmentValue 
FROM    TableA A
LEFT JOIN 
        (
          SELECT  StoreNumber ,MatNumber  , Date   , ShipmentValue
          FROM 
              (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreNumber, MatNumber ORDER BY DATE DESC ) AS ID,* 
                FROM TableB
              ) A 
          WHERE ID = 1
         ) B
ON   A.StoreNumber  = B.StoreNumber
AND  A.MatNumber    = B.MatNumber
```